# Oracle SP : PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "`" when expecting one of the following:

Tags: oracle, plsql, pls-00103

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE GDW_ARC_CDM.LND_DIM_GEO
SET DESCRIPTION_COLUMN = REPLACE( DESCRIPTION_COLUMN, '`', '''' )
WHERE CNTRY_ID         = 'KR'
AND SRC_ID             = 'KR_RET'
AND DESCRIPTION_COLUMN LIKE '%`%'';
     COMMIT;
```

I'm trying to add the above statement in Oracle SP, I m getting below error, the same query works in SQL Developer as a normal statement (not in SP).

Could you please suggest?

Answer (score 4):

Problem is in a fact that you have to enclose that `UPDATE` into single quotes (what you did), but taking care about other single quotes within that code. All of them have to be "doubled", or - a simpler and easier to read & maintain option - use the q-quoting mechanism.

Something like this:

```
SQL> select * From lnd_dim_geo;

DES CN SRC_ID
--- -- ------
x`y KR KR_RET

SQL> begin
  2    execute immediate q'[update lnd_dim_geo set description_column = replace(description_column, '`', '')
  3                         where cntry_id = 'KR' and src_id = 'KR_RET' and description_column like '%%']';
  4  end;
  5  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * From lnd_dim_geo;

DES CN SRC_ID
--- -- ------
xy  KR KR_RET

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is your original query then why you are using dynamic query at all.

You can use the following directly:

```
UPDATE LND_DIM_GEO
   SET
    DESCRIPTION_COLUMN = REPLACE(DESCRIPTION_COLUMN, '`', '')
 WHERE CNTRY_ID = 'KR'
   AND SRC_ID = 'KR_RET'
   AND DESCRIPTION_COLUMN LIKE '%%'
```